# How to dynamically axis scale limit for aes in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to annotate a ggplot histogram with a shaded rectangle, and am trying to figure out if there is a way to pass an argument to `ymax` that will dynamically scale the rectangle to the `ymax` of the plotting area.

I can achieve the desired effect by hard coding the ymax value of the `annotate()` to be greater than the plot `ymax` then 'cropping' back the plot using `coord_cartesian()` shown in the example below. However, this requires me to know a priori what the max of the histogram will be, which of course will change if I adjust `binwidth`. There is some way to scale `ymax` dynamically?

```
ggplot(
  data = mtcars,
  aes(
    x=mpg
  )
 )+
  geom_histogram(
    binwidth = 3,
    fill = "gray63"
  )+
  annotate(
    "rect",
    xmin = 21,
    xmax = 22,
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 10, #hardcode ymax to be > plot ymax
    fill = "gray18",
    alpha = 0.5
  )+
  theme_bw()
  coord_cartesian(
    ylim = c(0,8) #crop back to plot ymax
  )
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: `ymax = Inf` should work, if I understand what you want

Comment: That's it, you're a champ. Would you like to make it the answer so I can give to you the rep point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many position arguments can accept `Inf` or `-Inf`, setting them to whatever is the highest/lowest value currently shown. That's set by the plot limits, not necessarily the data. You can then drop the `coord_cartesian` bit, because you don't need to hard-code the limits any more.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 3, fill = "gray63") +
  annotate("rect", xmin = 21, xmax = 22, ymin = 0, ymax = Inf, fill = "gray18", alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

If, for whatever reason, you needed the plot to show a higher limit, you can see that `Inf` will then adjust accordingly:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 3, fill = "gray63") +
  annotate("rect", xmin = 21, xmax = 22, ymin = 0, ymax = Inf, fill = "gray18", alpha = 0.5) +
  ylim(0, 12)
```

[image]