# How to set variable x-axis and y-axis limits in a ggplot histogram that with a set number of breaks, rounded to different values?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, axis

I am trying to create histograms with distribution data on fire sizes within different provinces and fire zones. The sizes of fires, and the distribution of these sizes, varies drastically, so I want to make a for-loop to generate the histograms and to include limits on the x- and y-axes that can be adjusted in the loop to account for this variability. I also want these axes to have breaks at numbers that are easier to read (i.e., 0, 25, 50, 75, 125, 150 compared to 0, 45, 90, 135). Finally, I would like to have some vertical lines appear on the graph (i.e., 200 ha, median, mean, and max values) and would like their orientation to be variable based upon the maximum value on the y-axis of the particular graph (right now, the text for the "200 ha" line and the "bins = 100 ha" label are specified to be placed at y=150, but I would like that to be variable based upon the maximum y-axis value).

(I was able to dictate where along the x-axis I want some labels to go, because the x-axis has an associated vector/column in my dataframe, but this is harder to wrap my brain around for the y-axis since it is a histogram and the frequency isn't retrievable from a column in the df.)

Before I get to the for-loop, though, I am trying to work with a subset of my data to make sure that my base code for the graph is fine. And it's not!

I found that the annotate line will get me closer to ensuring the axes reach the full extent of the data, but the y-axis annoyingly does not show the maximum frequency value.

Code for the ugly figure:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

#make new df with fake data
new_year <- c(2009,2009,1988,1989,1991,2001,2008,2015,2020,1997,2012,2002,2012)
new_burn_size <- c(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.2,1.2,7.0,100.0,16711.0,18482.0,48400.0,48400.0,50727.1)
dat3 <- data.frame(new_year, new_burn_size)%>%
dplyr::mutate(fire_zone == 5)

#code
plot1 <- ggplot(dat3, aes(x=new_burn_size), group=1) +
geom_histogram(binwidth = 100, right = TRUE, origin = 0) +
labs(title = "1980-2023 QC Fire Distribution FZ5")+
scale_y_continuous(name = "Number of fires", limits=c(0,150))+
scale_x_continuous("Fire Size (1 ha minimum)")+
theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), 
      axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), legend.position = "none", axis.text.x =
      element_text(angle = 90, size = 10), plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, 
                                                                     face =  "bold"), 
      axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", size = 10), )+
geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 200), colour = "orange", linewidth =0.75)+
geom_text(aes(label="200 ha", y=150, x=200), colour = "orange", size = 4)+
geom_vline(aes(xintercept = max(new_burn_size)), colour = "#882255" ,linewidth=0.5, linetype = "dashed")+
geom_text(aes(label=paste("max:",round(max(new_burn_size))), y=125, x=max(new_burn_size)), col= "#882255", size=3)+
geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(new_burn_size)), colour = "#009E73" ,linewidth=0.5, linetype = "dashed")+
geom_text(aes(label=paste("mean:",round(mean(new_burn_size))), y=100, x=mean(new_burn_size)), col= "#009E73", size=3)+
geom_vline(aes(xintercept = median(new_burn_size)), colour = "#56B4E9" ,linewidth=0.5, linetype = "dashed")+
geom_text(label=paste("med:",round(median(new_burn_size))), y=50, x=median(new_burn_size)), col= "#56B4E9", size=3)+
annotate('text', x = 40000, y = 150, label = "bins = 100 ha")
```

The figure below uses the real data to show you what I'm up against. The text associated with the vertical lines are where I want them, but that's because I wrote in a value whereas I want that to be dynamic (e.g., 50% of ymax, 25% of ymax, or whatever works best). I just don't know how to figure that out using frequency values.
[image: ugly image]

I've tried stealing and reading the following documentation and posts, but still haven't managed to get what I want:

1. [How do I set a max y-axis limit based on the maximum value of a dataframe at any given time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65711760/how-do-i-set-a-max-y-axis-limit-based-on-the-maximum-value-of-a-dataframe-at-any)

This one almost gets it, but since I'm doing a histogram, I can't easily call the values for the y-axis.

2. [How to dynamically axis scale limit for aes in ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52192196/how-to-dynamically-axis-scale-limit-for-aes-in-ggplot)

I'm not entirely sold on this annotate line working, but I included it just in case.

3. [R ggplot loop: in a for loop of ggplot histograms, how can you automatically set the y axis scale based on max frequency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63058218/r-ggplot-loop-in-a-for-loop-of-ggplot-histograms-how-can-you-automatically-set)

Feels closer, but I want to keep my bin size at 100 and these suggestions only seem to work if bin size = 1. If I try to use the scale_y_continuous line, the breaks in my y-axis seem to only be 0 and 1. I also tried changing the 1 to 5 or 3 to this:

```
scale_y_continuous(name = "Number of fires", breaks=seq(0,max(table(x)),3))
```

and then I can only see 0 on the y-axis.

I am also open to suggestions for better scaling so the figure sucks less. This would also need to be dynamic, depending on data extents for each fire zone.

Please help!

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data. And please get rid of all the unnecessary packages. You are only using `ggplot2`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! Would it also be better to include the figure that uses the fake data?